# What doesn't my JavaScript layer automatically automatically format my JavaScript files?

Tags: spacemacs, javascript

When I open a JavaScript file, the file appears as plain text. When I activate `javascript-mode` in more (`SPC` `SPC`) on a .js file, then the file is correctly formatted.

I have the layer installed with the following configuration under `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`:

```
(javascript :variables
            javascript-backend 'tern
            javascript-fmt-tool 'prettier
            javascript-import-tool 'import-js
            node-add-modules-path t
            js2-include-node-externs t
            js2-strict-missing-semi-warning nil
            javascript-repl `nodejs)
```

I have been verifying my installation + configuration [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/javascript). I don't see anything out of the ordinary. [Here](https://github.com/cbillowes/dot/blob/master/.spacemacs) is my `.spacemacs` file for reference.

Comment: Do you have an entry for Javascript files in your `auto-mode-alist`? Probably somethings line ` ("\\.js[mx]?\\'" . javascript-mode)`.

Comment: If you are not in javascript-mode then in which mode are you in?

Comment: How do I check what mode I am in? Shouldn't it automatically detect it? My knowledge of spacemacs is limited, sorry.

Comment: @NickD I have `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsx?$" . "\\.js[x]?\\'"))` in dotspacemacs/user-config